# Javascript: How to remove empty string values from an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have this array of objects:

```js
const data = [{
    "_id": "plastic",
    "countries": ['Egypt','','Iran','',''],
    "likelihood": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "relevance": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "intensity": [1,2,3,4,5]
},
{
    "_id": "peak oil",
    "countries": ['USA','Russia',''],
    "likelihood": [1,2,3],
    "relevance": [1,2,3],
    "intensity": [1,2,3]
 }]
```

I want to remove empty strings in the countries array. Now here's the catch, I want to remove the same index in likelihood,relevance and intensity as well.

I tried this:

```js
// replacement for splice, array.remove(index)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
        var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
        this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
        return this.push.apply(this, rest);
      };
    
data.forEach(obj => {
        obj.countries.forEach((country,index) => {
          if (country === "") {
            obj.countries.remove(index)
            obj.likelihood.remove(index)
            obj.relevance.remove(index)
            obj.intensity.remove(index)
          }
        })
      })
```

Example output on the above data:

```js
[{
        "_id": "plastic",
        "countries": ['Egypt','Iran'],
        "likelihood": [1,3],
        "relevance": [1,3],
        "intensity": [1,3]
    },
    {
        "_id": "peak oil",
        "countries": ['USA','Russia'],
        "likelihood": [1,2],
        "relevance": [1,2],
        "intensity": [1,2]
 }]
```

As you can see the index which was empty in the countries array was removed along with likelihood,relevance,intensity.

How can I achieve this ?

**UPDATE**

I want multiple strings to be removed.

Comment: Not sure what you want? It correctly removes all values for me.

Comment: Could you please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (Minimal Reproducible example)? That would make solving very simple.

Comment: > And this doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

What do you mean, doesn't work? Any errors? Or the code doesn't return the predicted output? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. Can't say it's the cleanest approach, but it correctly removes the values.

```js
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

const data = [{
        "_id": "plastic",
        "countries": ['Egypt','','Iran'],
        "likelihood": [1,2,3],
        "relevance": [1,2,3],
        "intensity": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        "_id": "peak oil",
        "countries": ['USA','Russia',''],
        "likelihood": [1,2,3],
        "relevance": [1,2,3],
        "intensity": [1,2,3]
 }]

data.forEach(obj => {
  obj.countries.forEach((country, index) => {
    if (country === "") {
      obj.countries.remove(index)
      obj.likelihood.remove(index)
      obj.relevance.remove(index)
      obj.intensity.remove(index)
    }
  })
})

console.log(data);
```

However, in your code, you are directly editing `Array.prototype`. This is a bad practice and can cause issues in the future. Instead, you can directly use `Array.splice` to remove the items.

**EDIT:** This now remove all instances of empty strings

```js
const data = [{
    "_id": "plastic",
    "countries": ['Egypt', '', 'Iran', ''],
    "likelihood": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "relevance": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "intensity": [1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    "_id": "peak oil",
    "countries": ['', 'USA', 'Russia', ''],
    "likelihood": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "relevance": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "intensity": [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
]

const cleaned = data.map(thing => {
  while (thing.countries.includes('')) {
    const index = thing.countries.indexOf('');
    thing.countries.splice(index, 1);
    thing.likelihood.splice(index, 1);
    thing.relevance.splice(index, 1);
    thing.intensity.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return thing;
})

console.log(cleaned);
```

Comment: Doesn't work when there are are 2 or more empty strings !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a wrong solution.

Comment: @Codenewbie i didnt know there could be 2 or more. will updare.

Answer (score 1):

to remove, you can use `splice`

```js
const datas=[{
        "_id": "plastic",
        "countries": ['Egypt','','Iran'],
        "likelihood": [1,2,3],
        "relevance": [1,2,3],
        "intensity": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        "_id": "peak oil",
        "countries": ['USA','Russia',''],
        "likelihood": [1,2,3],
        "relevance": [1,2,3],
        "intensity": [1,2,3]
 }];

for (const i in datas){
    const rmIdx=datas[i]["countries"].findIndex(val=>val==="");
    for (const key of ["countries","likelihood", "relevance","intensity"]){
        datas[i][key].splice(rmIdx,1)
    }
}

console.log(datas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data.forEach(obj => {
        obj.countries.forEach((country,index) => {
          if (country === "") {
            obj.countries.remove(index)
            obj.likelihood.remove(index)
            obj.relevance.remove(index)
            obj.intensity.remove(index)
          }
        })
      })
```

with

```
data.forEach(obj => {
        obj.countries.forEach((country,index) => {
          if (country === "") {
            obj.countries.remove(index)
            obj.likelihood.splice(index) // Using splice is enough.
            obj.relevance.splice(index)
            obj.intensity.splice(index)
          }
        })
      })
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited::

if your data be like this :

```js
let data = [{
    "_id": "plastic",
    "countries": ['Egypt', '', 'Iran'],
    "likelihood": [1, 2, 3],
    "relevance": [1, 2, 3],
    "intensity": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    "_id": "plastic",
    "countries": ['Egypt', '', 'Iran', ''],
    "likelihood": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "relevance": [1, 2, 3, 5],
    "intensity": [1, 2, 3, 6]
  },
  {
    "_id": "peak oil",
    "countries": ['USA', 'Russia', ''],
    "likelihood": [1, 2, 3],
    "relevance": [1, 2, 3],
    "intensity": [1, 2, 3]
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let indexes = []
  let j = 0
  while ((j = data[i].countries.indexOf("", j + 1)) != -1) {
    indexes.push(j);
  }
  for (const key of ["countries", "likelihood", "relevance", "intensity"]) {
    for (let k = 0; k < indexes.length; k++) {
      data[i][key].splice(indexes[k] - k, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

you can do something like this :

```
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     let indexes=[]
     let j=0
while ((j = data[i].countries.indexOf("", j+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(j);
    }

  for(let k =0 ; k< indexes.length;k++){
       for (const key of ["countries","likelihood", "relevance","intensity"]){
        data[i][key].splice(indexes[k],1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to remove all other values too

Answer (score -1):

Filters all Falsy values .... :)

```js
const data = [{
        "_id": "plastic",
        "countries": ['Egypt','','Iran'],
        "likelihood": [1,2,3],
        "relevance": [1,2,3],
        "intensity": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        "_id": "peak oil",
        "countries": ['USA','Russia',''],
        "likelihood": [1,2,3],
        "relevance": [1,2,3],
        "intensity": [1,2,3]
 }]
 
const res = data.map(d => ({ ...d , countries : d.countries.filter(Boolean)}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: OP wants to remove all other values too

Answer (score -1):

Complete algorithm:

```js
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    const trackindices = []
    const countries = data[i].countries.filter(Boolean)
    for(let k=0; k<data[i].countries.length; k++) {
        if(data[i].countries[k] == '') {
            trackindices.push(k)
        }
    }
    data[i].countries = countries
    
    const likelihood = data[i].likelihood
    const relevance = data[i].relevance
    const intensity = data[i].intensity
    
    
   trackindices.forEach(index => {
        delete likelihood[index]
        delete relevance[index]
        delete intensity[index]
   })
   data[i].likelihood = likelihood.filter(element => element !== undefined)
   data[i].relevance = relevance.filter(element => element !== undefined)
   data[i].intensity = intensity.filter(element => element !== undefined)
}
```